# How to change mac terminal keybinding for color picker to execute the escape sequence instead?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, terminal.app

Every time I hit `command + shift + c` in the terminal app it opens a color picker. I would like this keybinding to instead send the escape sequence to the terminal to cancel the execution of the currently running command.

I have attempted to rewire this keybinding through the global settings app to no avail.

MacOS Monterey v12.1

Comment: You want Cmd-shift-c to send Ctrl-c? Isn't it just easier to hit Ctrl-c?

Comment: My control key is mapped to Cmd because i'm using a windows keyboard. I use Cmd + . to send the escape signal usually, but on my linux computer I use Ctrl + shift + c to send escape so I keep getting them mixed up.

Comment: The Control key means the same thing on Mac, Windows, and Linux. It makes sense to leave as Control on all platforms. For this reason, most people that use a Windows keyboard on a Mac map the Windows key to the Mac Command key.

Comment: If that was the case then I wouldn't have remapped it. On all computers that I use daily I require copy & paste to be "pinky + pointer finger" and switch tabs to be "thumb + ring finger", both with involved keys being in the exact same positions on the keyboard.

Comment: Ah, good point. I was only thinking within the context of terminals.

Comment: I'm a user of the Arc Browser, which uses Cmd+Shift+C for copying the current url, but I found myself accidently hitting this combo in other apps and the color picker kept coming up and it annoyed me, so I sussed out how to keep that from happening and realized it also answers this question.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To change this in the global settings for keyboard shortcuts in MacOS, you will need to override the Menu Items for "Show Colors" and "Hide Colors".  You can do this globally for All Applications, or just for specific applications.  Doing it for All Applications is more straightforward.

Steps:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Click Keyboard in the left side menu
3. Click the Keyboard Shortcuts button
4. In the Modal that opens, Click App Shortcuts on the left side menu
5. Click the + button to add a new shortcut
6. In the next Model that opens

   1. Set Application to "All Applications"
   2. Set Menu Title to "Show Colors"
   3. Set keyboard shortcut to some junk shortcut you'll never hit.  I chose `Ctrl+Alt+Shift + ]` , aka `Meh + ]`
   4. Click done
7. Repeat step 6, but add a new shortcut for "Hide Colors"

[image]